# Transfer User Data Around in Asp Net Core Razor

Tags: c#, webforms, razor-pages

In webforms i used to store users roles in

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket
```

and to store the user Real name to display I would store it in

```
Session["Name"]
```

or use a SessionManager class for strong typing

```
SessionManager.Name;
```

With this, I would like to know what is the best approach to deal with this in .Net Core Razor pages?

**EDIT**

May I add, authentication on the application is being done using LDAP access directory since we work on an intranet, so there is no need to store passwords.

Comment: Are you using .net core identity? You need to let go of some of the old webforms thinking and patterns but after some transition it will be worth it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Sorry i haven't been using identity 'cause i didn't like all those generated tables. I have been using cookie claims now and gave up on session. I'm not sure if i should explore identity a bit more though and i will update my main post